# How to check if element width is less than or equal to a pixel size in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

My goal is to write a test in Cypress that checks if the width of an element is less than or equal to 355px.

I have this code, but it only checks the exact dimension:

```js
cy
.get('.mat-dialog-container:visible')
.should('have.css', 'width', '355px')
```

Comment: Why are you testing this, with Cypress or at all? Also, why did you expect that wouldn't test the exact value?

Comment: I am testing this to make sure the element resizes correctly. This is easy to do in Cypress, where I can toggle the viewport easily. I don't want to test the exact value, because a scroll-bar might appear.

Comment: I would generally suggest using Cypress to test the actual *behaviour* of the app, things like responsive design are best reviewed manually.

Comment: I would have to strongly disagree. My perspective is that Cypress is _really_ good at testing responsive design - and manually testing is no testing. But that's another discussion :)

Comment: LOL you don't have to do much real-world testing to see that layout can regress just as much as behavior.

Comment: You can tackle a lot of layout with Percy, see [Testing how an application renders a drawing with Cypress and Percy.io](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/testing-visually/). WRT to scrollbar visibility, it should be consistent for a fixed test fixture.

Comment: Cypress is an excellent example of tooling that helps when you have a team of developers working on the same interfaces or elements. Someone may change something that affects layout or element size further breaking a site or app. Having tests to ensure the width of elements is what you expect really helps everyone follow the same guidelines and ensures that tests are consistently performed.

I'm aware these comments are over a few years old now, and perspectives may have changed, however, I wanted to add an up-to-date perspective as web technology moves quickly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Anything that can be automated, should be (unless the expected utility of doing so is outweighed by the cost of implementation and maintenance, [of course](https://xkcd.com/1319/)), thus I think that automating RD tests is a good idea. Whether checking container dimensions is the way to achieve it is an open question (one could say that you should instead check wether elements that should be hidden, are hidden, and elements which should be visible, are visible, and whether the UI is working as expected).

Alas, here's how to achieve what you want.

I'd go with jQuery's [`outerWidth`](https://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)  which is what you will usually want to check instead of `width` (in case there's `padding` or `border`):

```js
cy.get(selector).invoke('outerWidth').should('be.lt', 355);
```

If you really wish to assert the actual computed css value, you can indeed use jQuery [`css`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) helper (or use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), it doesn't really matter):

```js
cy.get(selector).invoke('css', 'width')
    .then(str => parseInt(str)).should('be.lt', 355);

// or use jQuery.prototype.width (I'm not sure if there's any meaningful
//  difference, but there might be --- better check the docs)
cy.get(selector).invoke('width').should('be.lt', 355);
```

Comment: Retry-ability is not considered here. See here for a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883798/1168594
and here for official cypress docu:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability#Correctly-waiting-for-values

Answer (score 8):

Just tried this code recently and it works perfectly in my sytem.

**

```
cy.get('.vc_icon_element-inner')
.invoke('height').should('be.greaterThan', 47).and('be.lessThan',50)
```

**

In this the **Invoke** function by default takes the Height CSS from the get parameter .vc_icon_element-inner trimming the *px* value from the field and takes integer.

Should assertion checks the range within the given range and shows the output.

**Working screenshot**

[image: Working screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I used this to get the width of an element (a canvas in this case)

```
 cy.get("#canvas").then(function(objCanvas) {
     var width = objCanvas.prop("width")
     var height = objCanvas.prop("height")
     var style = objCanvas.prop("style")
     cy.log("Width: "+width)
     cy.log("Height: "+height)
     cy.log("Style :"+style)
 })

 cy.get('#canvas').invoke('width').then(function(owidth){
     cy.log(owidth)
 });

 cy.get('#canvas').invoke('height').then(function(oHeight){
     cy.log(oHeight)
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers given won't retry properly. That is, if you try `cy.get(selector).invoke('width').should('be.lt', 355)`, Cypress will retry the `should` but not the `invoke`, so if the width wasn't what was expected initially, it won't work. This can lead to flakiness.

A better way of doing it, which will retry as expected is:

```
cy.get(selector).should(el => expect(el.width()).lt(355))
```

Comment: This is the total right answer and should be marked as accepted. See here in the official cypress docu: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability#Correctly-waiting-for-values

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Simple but super

```
cy.get('.mat-dialog-container')
.should('be.visible')
.and((.mat-dialog-container) => {
    expect(.mat-dialog-container.naturalWidth).to.be.lessThan(356);
    });
```